# What is the straightest line I can make using a linear combination of time series

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning

I have 3 processes which generate an output in the form of a time series.

[image]

I want to choose a linear combination of the processes that will result in the straightest line possible (I think this property might be called [Sinuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity))

A trivial solution would be `0*A + 0*B + 0*C` which will always give a straight line,  but this isn't very useful.

How can I calculate the non-trivial solution(s)?

It feels like a Linear Regression problem but I can't see a way to reduce to that.

Comment: Time series data are typically a combination of (say) trend, seasonality, & noise. Are you wanting just a linear combination of the trends? How are you thinking of the different components relative to your task?

Comment: Are you sure sinuosity is the statistics you want? Sinuosity is the ratio of the lengths of the path to the shortest path, this sounds quite different from your question's description.

Comment: @gung, I understand, but a simple linear combination of the entire series without looking at sub-components will be ok for my purposes.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, maybe not but I wanted to give a metric for the 'straighess' of a line. My understanding is that minimizing the sinuosity should give the straightest line. I'm open to suggestions for a better metric

Comment: We will need your thoughts about how to measure "straightest." If you believe $\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma C$ is "straight," then by almost any measure in which $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ is ruled out, the line $\mu + \lambda(\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma C)$ is going to be equally "straight." This suggests there will not be a unique solution and shows that the measure of "straightness" cannot merely be a sum of squares of deviations, for instance, nor can it be "sinuosity" (or tortuosity) in their usual senses.

Comment: @whuber, I only care about α,β,and γ. if it helps, I only care about solutions where μ=0 and λ=1

Comment: The problem, Mark, is that these numbers are not defined, even when $\mu=0$. Any solution $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,1)$ gives a line that apparently is as "straight" as $(\zeta\alpha, \zeta\beta, \zeta\gamma, 1)$.  In fact, the smaller $|\zeta|$ becomes, the straighter it looks (and the lower its sinuosity becomes), until in the limit $\zeta=0$ it is the perfectly straight solution you have rejected.  Which of these infinitely many solutions should be chosen?

Comment: @whuber, hmm I see your point now. 

I guess what I'm looking for is the relative ratio of processes that will allow them to, in a sense, cancel each other out as much as possible. Is there a better name for this?

Comment: You will need to propose a quantitative way to measure degree of "cancellation."  If you can do that yourself that would be great; but if not, just try to tell us in words what "cancellation" means in your application and try to give us a sense of what your analysis is meant to achieve.  Then we might be able to propose reasonable measures for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20991/discussion-between-mark-dunne-and-whuber).

Comment: Get the first PCA component.

Answer (score 4):

Proximity of a function $f$ to "straightness" measures the extent to which $f$ is "close" to a linear function of time.  Great flexibility and power to specify straightness can be achieved by extending the linear functions, which are linear combinations of the constant function $1$ and the identity function $t\to t$, to a basis $E$ of the (Hilbert) space of $L^2$ integrable functions of the set of times.

Conventional extensions include the polynomials

$$E = (e_0, e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_k, \ldots) = (1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^k, \ldots)$$

but can be any set of linearly independent functions.  Intuitively, the further out we go into one of these bases, the more we "depart from linearity."

Given $p$ time series

$$\mathrm{x}_i = ((t_1, x_{i1}), (t_2, x_{i2}), \ldots, (t_j, x_{ij}), \ldots, (t_n, x_{in}))$$

let us compute their projections onto the first $p+1$ elements of this basis using ordinary least squares, giving

$$x_{ij} = b_{i0} + b_{i1}t_j + b_{i2}e_2(t_j) + \cdots + b_{ip}e_p(t_j) + \varepsilon_{ij}.$$

We seek a linear combination of the $\mathrm{x}_i$, with coefficients $\mathbf{\lambda} = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_p)$ that is "straightest" in the sense that all the coefficients of $e_j$ for $j\gt 1$ vanish.  That is,

$$\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i b_{ij} = 0, \ j = 2, 3, \ldots, p.$$

This is the most we can hope for with $p$ series: if we tried to make one more coefficient vanish, we would have $p$ simultaneous linear equations governing the $\lambda_i$ and usually only $\lambda_i=0$ would be the solution.  By invoking only $p-1$ equations, we are guaranteed to have a system with a nontrivial kernel.

We are left to choose a basis element of that kernel.  Assuming it is just one-dimensional (which will generically be the case), we may impose one more condition.  A convenient one is to make the resulting linear combination look like an arithmetic mean of the time series.  I do that by standardizing it so that its variance is $1/p$ times the collective variance of all the time series data.  This can easily be done in two steps: first, require that the coefficients sum to unity:

$$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \ldots + \lambda_p = 1.$$

Then, perform the standardization.  All other solutions will be linear functions of this one plus a linear function of time.

Let's turn to a worked example.  This proposal is implemented in the following `R` code, which generates an array of time series (which may have irregular spacing and multiple observations per time), finds the coefficients $b_{ik}$ using least squares fits, adjoins the sum-to-unity vector $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$ to this matrix, and solves for $\lambda$.  That directly produces the linear combination of the original series, $\sum_{i}\lambda_i \mathrm{x}_i$, which is then standardized.  The original series are plotted (in color, using dashed lines) and the "straightest" linear combination is overplotted (black solid line) for comparison.

[image: Figure]

```R
#
# Specify the problem.
#
n <- 96            # Number of time steps
k <- 1             # Observations per time step
p <- 5             # Number of series
shape <- 3         # Higher (positive) values make times more evenly spaced
set.seed(17)       # Makes the results reproducible
#
# Create time series, one per column of `y`.  The times themselves are in `times`.
#
q <- p
times <- rep(c(cumsum(rgamma(n, shape, shape)), NA), k)
n.k <- length(times)
beta <- round(matrix(rnorm(q*p), q), 1)
y <- matrix(rnorm(q*n.k), ncol=p) %*% beta + 
  100 * outer(times, 1:p, function(i,j) sin(2*j*i/n)) + rnorm(p*n.k, sd=sqrt(n.k))
#
# Construct fits using a basis of orthogonal polynomials.
#
x <- times; x[is.na(times)] <- 0 # (`poly` chokes on NA values, so zero them out)
basis <- poly(x, degree=p-1)     # Includes a linear term
fits <- apply(y, 2, function(z) coef(lm(z ~ basis)))
fits["(Intercept)", ] <- 1       # Make coefficients sum to unity
lambda <- solve(fits, c(1, rep(0, p-1)))
y.hat <- y %*% lambda
#
# Standardize the combination to look like an average of the time series
#
y.hat <- (y.hat - mean(y.hat, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(y.hat, na.rm=TRUE) * 
  sd(y, na.rm=TRUE) / sqrt(p) + mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)
#
# Display the results.
#
colors <- as.list(rainbow(p))
times.range <- range(times, na.rm=TRUE)
plot(times.range, range(c(y, y.hat), na.rm=TRUE), type="n",
     xlab="Time", ylab="Value", main="Data and Fit")
invisible(mapply(function(z, c) lines(times, z, col=c, lwd=2, lty=3), 
                 as.data.frame(y), colors))
lines(times, y.hat, lwd=2, col="Black", lty=1)
```

Comment: Wow. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 3):

In a fairly practical sense, one nice and simple way to get "a linear combination close to a straight line" in one particular sense -- at least from data sampled at regular intervals -- would be to regress the time index (1,2,...) on the series A, B, C. That is, fit a least squares regression `y ~ A + B + C` where `y` is simply a linearly increasing set of values.

It will be as close as it can get (in the least squares sense) to the chosen line, but it won't necessarily be especially *smooth*.

You can then scale the coefficients of A,B, and C by a common arbitrary constant, or shift the intercept (e.g. to zero, if you like).

(I make no claims that doing what you're attempting is meaningful, but if that's really what you want to do, this straight OLS regression approach would be the first thing I'd try - it's simple to do, and easy to explain to people. If you want to minimize something other than the plain sum of squares of deviations from a straight line, then of course there are ways to do that.)

---

Example: I start with whuber's matrix `y` from his code.

```
> ys=as.data.frame(cbind(y,1:97))
> colnames(ys)<-c(LETTERS[1:5],"t")
> tfit=lm(t~.,ys)
> plot(fitted(tfit),type="l")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that we were after a flat function, but re-reading I can see that wasn't actually what was requested... That substantially complicates the problem I think...

Comment: I had tried this approach (regressing $1$ against the time series together with the time itself, which is essentially your proposal) but was unsatisfied with the results--they tended not to look straight at all.

Comment: @whuber -- I think that you perhaps misunderstood what I was saying to do (or at least what I intended to convey). See my example (based on your $y$ data). It looks reasonably straight to me. My answer does not interpret "linear combination of the processes that will result in the straightest line" to mean that the straight line should have slope 0, as analystic's comment under my answer notes. I don't think it's the best possible answer, but it is quite fast.

Comment: I interpreted it correctly. Remember the question of normalization: you can make the result look as smooth as you like via a suitable linear transformation. Our two results look similar *for the kinds of data I generated.* To see how they might differ, (1) normalize my `y.hat` by dividing by `(6*sqrt(p))` instead of `sqrt(p)` and (2) replace `sin(2*j*i/n))` in the data generation process by `sin(2*j^2*i/n))`. That makes it clear the two approaches give different results. I chose the method in my answer because (a) it is flexible and (b) it handles errors in the data more naturally.

Comment: @whuber I didn't at any stage think your method and the approach I suggested previously would give similar results.

Comment: (I did not mean to suggest they should--but sometimes they do.) BTW, if you would like to make more comparisons, I suggest making your code a little more flexible (rather than hard-wiring it for five time series and evenly-spaced times) and running it right after the end of my example: `ys=as.data.frame(cbind(y,times));
colnames(ys)<-c(LETTERS[1:p],"t");
tfit=lm(t~.,ys);
lines(times[!is.na(times)],fitted(tfit),type="l")`  Then try setting (say) `k<-4; p<-3` at the beginning.  It is very instructive to see how the two methods compare.  I appreciate your efforts to apply your method to my data!

Comment: @whuber I greatly appreciate you taking the time to discuss this issue with me; you're invariably helpful. I want to spend some time looking at this more carefully than I am able to right now (as you may already have picked up, my brain is a little on the slow side right now). So I will come back and look at this again (but more closely) later today.

Comment: I am glad you are interested, Glen.  You have already pointed to a way I can improve my solution: I don't have to include the linear term, allowing me to add in one more basis element.  (`basis <- poly(x, degree=p)[, -1]`)  What I have also found helpful is to compare solutions by (1) normalizing the coefficients to a unit $L^2$ norm and (2) regressing the solution against time and studying the residuals.

Comment: Can it be estimated that y.hat preserves the same "straighness" when calcluated using the same parameters on the data coming from the same generator, but not actually seen during training?